# FlatFileFooterCallback - how to get access to StepExecution For Count

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am reading from Oracle and writing to a CSV file. I have one step which reads and writes to the CSV file. I implemented a ChunkListener so I know how many records were written.

I want to be able to write a file trailer showing the number of records written to my file. I implemented FlatFileFooterCallback but cannot figure out how to get the data from StepExecution (the "readCount") to my FlatFileFooterCallback.

I guess I am struggling with how to get access to Job, Step scopes in my write.

Any examples, or links would be helpful. I am using [Spring Batch / Boot] so I am all annotated. I can find xml examples, so maybe this annotated stuff is more complicated.

```
ItemWriter<Object> databaseCsvItemWriter() {

    FlatFileItemWriter<Object> csvFileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

    String exportFileHeader = "one,two,three";
    StringHeaderWriter headerWriter = new StringHeaderWriter(exportFileHeader);
    csvFileWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerWriter);

    String exportFilePath = "/tmp/students.csv";
    csvFileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(exportFilePath));

    LineAggregator<McsendRequest> lineAggregator = createRequestLineAggregator();
    csvFileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);

    csvFileWriter.setFooterCallback(headerWriter);

    return csvFileWriter;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `CustomFooterCallback` as follows:

```
public class CustomFooterCallback implements FlatFileFooterCallback {

    @Value("#{StepExecution}")
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("footer - number of items read: " + stepExecution.getReadCount());
        writer.write("footer - number of items written: " + stepExecution.getWriteCount());
    }

}
```

Then in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileFooterCallback customFooterCallback() {
    return new CustomFooterCallback();
}
```

And use in the `Writer`:

```
csvFileWriter.setFooterCallback(customFooterCallback());
```

This way, you have access to `StepExecution` in order to read data as needed.