# Access to stepExecution inside FlatFileFooterCallback

Tags: spring-batch

I am creating a fixed length file I have to attached the number of files that are read in to the footer.  I need to access the the stepExecution to get the write count, I followed this [FlatFileFooterCallback - how to get access to StepExecution For Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190143/flatfilefootercallback-how-to-get-access-to-stepexecution-for-count).  StepExecution is null??

FlatFileFooterCallback

public class LexisNexisRequestFileFooter implements FlatFileFooterCallback {

```
@Value("#{StepExecution}")
private StepExecution stepExecution;
int totalItemsWritten = 0;

@Override
public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(stepExecution.getWriteCount());
    String julianDate = createJulianDate();
    String SAT = "##!!SAT#"+julianDate+totalItemsWritten+"                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \r\n";
    String SIT = "##!!SIT#"+julianDate+totalItemsWritten+"                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \r\n";
    String footer = SAT+SIT;
    writer.write(footer);

}
```

}

Configuration file

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileFooterCallback customFooterCallback() {
    return new LexisNexisRequestFileFooter();
}
```

Writer file

```
    // Create writer instance
    FlatFileItemWriter<LexisNexisRequestRecord> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

    LexisNexisRequestFileFooter lexisNexisRequestFileFooter = new LexisNexisRequestFileFooter();

    writer.setFooterCallback(lexisNexisRequestFileFooter);

    // Set output file location
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("homeData.txt"));

    // All job reptitions should append to same output file
    writer.setAppendAllowed(true);

    writer.setEncoding("ascii");
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: The linked answer is correct. You need to declare the FooterCallback as a step-scoped bean and you will be able to inject the step execution in it.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have posted my code, stepExecution is still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your writer configuration, you are creating the footer callback manually here:

```
LexisNexisRequestFileFooter lexisNexisRequestFileFooter = new LexisNexisRequestFileFooter();
writer.setFooterCallback(lexisNexisRequestFileFooter);
```

and not injecting the step scoped bean. Your item writer bean definition method should be something like:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter writer() {

   // Create writer instance
   FlatFileItemWriter<LexisNexisRequestRecord> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

   writer.setFooterCallback(customFooterCallback());

   // Set output file location
   writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("homeData.txt"));

   // All job reptitions should append to same output file
   writer.setAppendAllowed(true);

   writer.setEncoding("ascii");
}
```